# How Jenkins plugins works

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I had a situation where I have developed my own Jenkins plugin for the first time. The main purpose of the plugin is to publish a message to Google Cloud Platform. All the code that I have written in Jenkins is working fine in the local environment from eclipse. But when I am using the same code in Jenkins it is causing some dependency errors. Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you.

**Note:** Jenkins and Eclipse are on the same machine
How Jenkins resolves its dependencies is really a concern here for me.

Comment: Share error log and pom file. With this information you can't get help to your issue.

Comment: Error is like **No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp or grpc-netty artifact**

Comment: <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
     <version>0.20.1-beta</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
<artifactId>gax</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-auth-library-credentials</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse uses the M2eclipse plugin to add your dependencies to the classpath when running your plugin from Eclipse.

Jenkins only resolves dependencies between plugins. Furthermore Jenkins expects the .hpi packages to be self-contained, i.e. containing all JAR dependencies you need. `mvn package` should copy the jars of all your dependencies and put them in the .hpi file in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

In your specific case it seems that the Google Cloud implementation expects some implementation of a channel service provider on the classpath, so you should add a dependency on grpc-okhttp or grpc-netty, so they get packaged into the .hpi file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there could be a choice of class loader issue so please add follwing lines of code before calling classes of Google.

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());

Also add the following code in Jenkins plugin pom.xml to specify Jenkins that the dependencies in the pom.xml should be loaded first rather than Jenkins dependencies.

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-hpi-plugin</artifactId>
          **<configuration>
            <pluginFirstClassLoader>true</pluginFirstClassLoader>
          </configuration>**
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```